# Correctly predicting salt and sugar in the proper sequence.

Tags: probability

We have $10$ canisters, $5$ containing sugar and $5$ containing salt. What is the probability of naming them all in the correct order? (example: salt, sugar, sugar, salt, sugar, salt, salt, ...)

It's different from predicting $10$ coins head or tails, because there are limited quantities of each.

Thanks.

Comment: Can we taste a canister in between naming it and naming the next one?

Comment: @Michael: That wouldn't help, because you have to get them all right. So at each stage you have to assume that all your previous guesses were correct.

Comment: Table sugar has bigger crystals than table salt so you should be able to identify them with probability 1.

Answer (score 3):

You have $\dbinom{10}{5}=252$ different options, so the probability is $\dfrac{1}{252}$

Comment: If the order doesn't matter, it is a Combination.
 If the order does matter it is a Permutation. So shouldn't you be doing a permutation?

Comment: It might be nice to explain why that is so, i.e. that you are picking which canisters will be full of sugar, hence implicitly determining the canisters which will contain salt.

Comment: @MathApprentice: You have *sugar* and *salt*. I think it's a good enough description to allow you to assume that you cannot tell the difference between a *salt* and a *salt* or a *sugar* and a *sugar*. In other words, there is no such thing as *order* here (except for the order between the salts and the sugars of course).

Comment: Then, @barakmanos, we have 10 canisters, each containing white powder. what is the probability of naming the white powders in the correct order? Ordering still matters with respect to the names.

Comment: @user2127595: You simply have $252$ options to choose from, so the probability that you guess correctly is the inverse of that. As hard as I think about it, there is nothing else to explain.

Comment: @MathApprentice: If they have labels (1 to 10) on them, then you're right. In fact, if there is anything unique about them then you're right. But if all there is to say about them is "white powder", then it can be assumed that they are distinguishable only by that character. And in this case, since it's the only specified character, they are not distinguishable at all (in between themselves), hence the answer to your question is $1$. In short, given such question with a list of possible characteristics, you can assume that there is no other characteristic involved.

Comment: Let's bring it down to 3 containers. If we had to name them in the correct order, wouldn't there be 1/8 possibilities of being correct?

Comment: @MathApprentice: What is the contents of each container? 2 salts and 1 sugar? 2 sugars and 1 salt?

Comment: @MathApprentice: The assumption is that you know there are 5 sugars and 5 salts, so you aren't going to make a guess that contains, say, 4 sugars and 6 salts.  So instead of $2^{10}$ possible guesses, there are only $\binom{10}{5}.$  About order: the order of the salts and sugars matters of course, but that's not what $\binom{10}{5}$ refers to.  To make a guess, you have to guess which five of the ten canisters are salt. (The rest are sugar.)  In this, order doesn't matter.  If I guess that canisters 1, 3, 4, 6, and 7 are salt, that's the same as guessing that 6, 4, 7, 1, and 3 are salt.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to look at this problem is to first simplify it by assuming there are only $4$ canisters.  Let A = salt and B = sugar.  Then the possible outcomes are AABB, ABAB, ABBA, BAAB, BABA, BBAA.  To determine the number of arrangements of A and B so there that are exactly $2$ of each, just "place" the $2$ As and the $2$ Bs must fill in the other spots.  There are $4 \choose 2$ = $6$ ways to place the $2$ As.  So if we were to guess the order for this simplified example, assuming we remembered to guess a pair of As and a pair of Bs, we would have a $1$ in $6$ chance of guessing correctly.  For $10$ canisters the logic/method is the same except it would be ${10 \choose 5}^{-1}$ = $1$ / $252$ = about $0.3968254$% probability.

Yes this is different than predicting $10$ fair coin flips but if you first told us that you got $5$ heads and $5$ tails, then it would be the same as this sugar/salt problem.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that each arrangement of $5$ salt and $5$ sugar canisters are equally likely, then any given arrangement is uniquely determined by the placement of, say, the $5$ sugar canisters among the $10$ canisters total.  For example, we can describe one arrangement as $(2, 3, 5, 7, 10)$, meaning that the sugar canisters are found in positions $2$, $3$, $5$, $7$, $10$ (and the salt canisters are in positions $1$, $4$, $6$, $8$, $9$).  Then clearly, there are exactly $$\binom{10}{5} = 252$$ ways to select $5$ distinct numbers from the set $\{1, 2, \ldots, 10\}$, representing the *positions* of the sugar canisters, and since each such selection is equally likely (by assumption), the probability of randomly choosing the *unique* correct representation is $1/252$.